# Backslashes in python POST request data

Tags: python

I need to send a post request with this data:

```
{
    "operationName": "Add",
    "variables":
    {
        "input":
        {
            "Id": "10000"
        }
    },
    "query": "mutation NMut($input: FUI!) {\n  fU(input: $input) {\n    flowe{\n      fBU{\n        iFBM\n      }\n      id\n    }\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

Every new request I need to change the `Id` variable and I do it like this

```
data = {
    "operationName": "Add",
    "variables":
    {
        "input":
        {
            "Id": f"{id}"
        }
    },
    "query": "mutation NMut($input: FUI!) {\n  fU(input: $input) {\n    flowe{\n      fBU{\n        iFBM\n      }\n      id\n    }\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

However, if I try to get `len(data)`, then I get

```
length = 3
```

It is likely that the case is in backslashes. How to correctly substitute the `Id` variable in data so that there is no conflict with backslashes?

Comment: `data` is a dict, so `len` gives you the number of key-value pairs, which indeed is 3 (one for `operationName`, `variables`, and `query` respectively). The substitution of the `id` variable (which is a poor name because that is a built-in python function) and newline characters are completely unrelated.

Comment: Please read [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). I couldn't resist and reformated your code to make it readable. Btw: Your example data is to complex for a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please read also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap it like below:

```
data = {"operationName":"Add","variables":{"input":{"Id":f"{id}"}},"query":"""mutation NMut($input: FUI!) {\n  fU(input: $input) {\n    flowe{\n      fBU{\n        iFBM\n      }\n      id\n    }\n  }\n}\n"""}
```

Comment: Your code is un-readable and I also assume it is buggy. Please read [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and upgrade your answer with nice looking code and some explanatioin.